# Increment value by 1 on each iteration in map

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

Hey guys i am new to Kotlin and want to see what is the easiest way to increment value of a map by 1 on each iteration, here is my attempts

This is how my map looks like.

```
val countByStatus: MutableMap<ImportStatus, Int> = mutableMapOf()

when (val count = csv.countByStatus[rowResult.status])

    {

        null -> csv.countByStatus[rowResult.status] = 1

        else -> csv.countByStatus[rowResult.status] = count + 1

    }
```

or

```
csv.countByStatus.merge(rowResult.status, 1, Int::plus)
```

or

```
csv.countByStatus.merge(rowResult.status, 1, { a: Int?, b: Int? -> a!! + b!! })
```

Comment: Did your results show all 3 approaches are valid, i.e. do they work? If so, which one looks easiest to you?

Comment: I don't see any loop in your code. What iterations you are talking about?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь I think by iteration they really mean each time this bit of code is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though technically a matter of opinion, I think it's pretty obvious in this case that `Int::plus` is more concise and easier to read than the lambda. Your lambda could be cleaned up since the inputs are not nullable according to the method's documentation. It could be `{ a: Int, b: Int -> a + b }` or just `{ a, b -> a + b }`. Personally, I still think `Int::plus` is a little cleaner.

`merge` is a JVM function that isn't in the Kotlin standard library, so you might want to avoid it if you're working on a project that you might take multi-platform later with Kotlin native. If that's the case, you could use `getOrDefault` to do this a little more concisely than your first way of doing it. I think defining it as an extension function would make it significantly cleaner at the use site since you are working with indirect property references.

```
fun <K> MutableMap<K, Int>.incrementValue(key: K) {
    this[key] = getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1
}
```

```
csv.countByStatus.incrementValue(rowResult.status)
```

Comment: So you suggest for me to add a function that will be responsible for incrementing the value of the exact key in map , one question how to access incrementValue from countByStatus also regarding Int::plus how would i use it without merge, thanks man just learning

Comment: You can define the `incrementValue` extension function anywhere that's in scope of where you're calling it. For general use utility functions like this, I define them at the top level (not inside any class). I'm not sure what you're asking about how to use `Int::plus` without merge. It's a function reference, but it's not very useful for anything but passing it to a higher order function like `merge`. If you had two Ints to add, you could just use `+` to add them.

Comment: So i end up going with extension function since its clear this way , i also did not know you can do that in kotlin , thank you man